# Creating a python game, dealing with lists

Tags: python

So I'm creating a very basic python game and I need some help with this step I'm stuck at.  The concept of the game is for the program to roll two die and add the sums.  With that number they can choose a number available from the number list (1-10) to "peg".  They keep going until all numbers are pegged or are out of options.  Earlier in the program I created two functions that I'm using in this step.  Those two are ask_number and valid_moves.  Basically the ask number just asks them which number they want to peg but it doesn't actually peg the number yet.  The valid_moves function just checks which numbers are still available for the player to select.

The game pretty much just looks like this halfway through:

```
------------------------------
(1)(2)(3)(4)(X)(6)(7)(X)(9)(X)
------------------------------
```

The X are the numbers that were already pegged.  In this part of the game I need to figure out how to replace the number with "X".  I have this so far but I know I am way off and I am having trouble with figuring out what to do.  (pegholes is the name of the list and move is the number they picked in the ask_number function).  Thanks so much!

```
PEGGED = "X"

def enter_peg(pegholes, roll, total):
    ask_number()
    if ask_number == valid_moves():
        pegholes.append(ask_number(PEGGED))

        return pegholes, move
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really not sure how your game is supposed to work, but this may help you out:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random
import sys

pegs = range(2, 11)

def roll_dice():
    return random.randint(1, 5) + random.randint(1, 5)

while True:
    roll = roll_dice()
    print "You rolled %s" %roll
    available_choices = set(p for p in pegs if p != 'X') - set(range(roll+1, 11))
    if len(available_choices) == 0:
        print "FAIL SAUCE"
        sys.exit()
    while True:
        choice = raw_input("Choose a number %s: " % (", ".join(str(x) for x in sorted(list(available_choices)))))
        if choice == 'q':
            sys.exit()
        choice = int(choice)
        if choice in available_choices:
            break
        print "Nice try buddy... pick a number in range, that hasn't been picked"
    pegs[choice - 2] = 'X'
    print "".join("(%s)" % p for p in pegs)
    if len([x for x in pegs if x == 'X']) == 9:
        print "WINNER!"
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you're trying to do...

- When you say "add the sum" you mean add them together to get a sum, right?
- Standard dice add up to 12 and two dice can't total 1 so for a fair game you want to go from  2 - 12

You could try something like this:

```
import random


#set up list of numbers from 2 to 10
numlist = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

#create a roll dice function, producing the sum of two random integers 1-6
def rolldice():
    return (random.randint(1,6) + random.randint(1,6))

#run the rolldice function
roll = rolldice()

#set up a loop for while the sum of the roll appears in the list
while roll in numlist:
    print "Your rolled %s" %roll
    print "Your list was", numlist

    print "Replacing %s with X" %roll

    numlist[numlist.index(roll)]="X"
    print "Your new list is", numlist
    raw_input("Press enter to roll again")
    roll = rolldice()

#once a roll not in the list show up:
print "Your roll was %s" %roll
print "This is not in your list"
```

You could also add another if statement to ask the user if they want to try again if the roll is not on the list... and then go back through the while loop.

Keep trying -- I was new to all of this last summer and am still learning.  Just keep trying different things... you will learn from your mistakes.